# Linux Debian Jessie - Failure to load operating system

Tags: linux, debian

When I start my machine (Lenovo X61s) I have the following error as written below - text below is exactly as it appears on my screen:

```
error: failure reading sector 0x802 from 'hd0'.
Entering rescue mode...
grub rescue>
```

With the above error I am unable to do anything, the machine starts and goes straight to /comes up with the error. I am wondering if there is a code which can be entered to force the machine to look enable rescue / look for the operating system? because it would appear to a novice, that the machine has somehow lost sight of the operating system? 
I should add that the last time the machine was shut down everything was working normally.

Thanks in advance for any advice / guidance which anyone can offer.

Comment: Did you do anything in particular just before this started happening?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is enough information to properly answer this question.

My suggestion would be to use a rescue USB/CD to mount your hard drive/partition to reinstall your boot loader on `hd0`.